# How I can Filter admin Order collection by status (Pending Only)?

Tags: magento2, collection, sales-order, order-grid

How can I filter admin order collection and showing only pending orders in grid?

So how can I extend it in custom module? Any suggestion about that?

Comment: Their would be only one table for order collection, not like frontend, admin side order collection. @mahmoudismail

Comment: @Learing_Coder how i can set filter to sale order grid collection?

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory')->create();
$orderCollection = $orderCollectionFactory
                ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('pending_payment')))
                ->setOrder('created_at','desc');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($orderCollection->getData());
echo "</pre>";
```

You will get all the pending order in this collection !!!